# How can I generate both standard accessors and fluent accessors with lombok?

Tags: java, accessor, lombok

I tried this.

```java
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@lombok.Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)
private String prop;
```

And `@Accessor` took precedence and `getProp` and `setProp` are not generated.

How can I make it generate this?

```java
public String getProp() {
    return prop;
}

public String prop() {
    //return prop;
    return getProp(); // wow factor
}

public void setProp(String prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
}

public Some prop(String prop) {
    //this.prop = prop;
    setProp(prop); // wow factor, again
    return this;
}
```

Comment: This feature has been requested multiple times on GitHub but the issues are still open ([#1595](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1595), [#2141](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2141) and [#3265](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3265)).  You could try putting likes on them.  Actually the only workaround is the one proposed by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible. You need to implement own getters and setters, and add @Getter @Setter and @Accessors(fluent = true) annotaions to achieve this.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class SampleClass {
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

In result you will have class like:

```
public class SampleClass {
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int id(){
        return id;
    }

    public SampleClass id(int id){
        this.id=id;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit late to the party. Found that using the Lombok annotations in the following combination that there is not need to add setters and getters. So in the above example the getId() and setId(...) can just be left out. ```@Data
@Accessors(fluent = true)```

Comment: @mornejvr I tried what you suggest but got the error "cannot find symbol setFirstName(java.lang.String)" using Lombok version 1.6.12, which version did you use?

Comment: @Bruno, I am using 1.18.8. It might be that it only works with newer versions of Lombok

Comment: I would prefer to use @Data instead of both getter and setter, though note you get more than just getter and setter with it. At least in my years of use of the library I always benefited from what Data provides.

Answer (score 13):

I'm afraid you can't.

From the [doc](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors.html) (emphasis is mine):

> The `@Accessors` annotation is used **to configure** how lombok generates and looks for getters and setters.

So `@Accessors` doesn't generate anything, it's just a way to configure `@Getter` and `@Setter`.

---

If you really want fluent **and** regular getter/setter, you can add (manually) the regular one and make them delegate to the fluent ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Setter @Getter
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int height;
}

....

@Test
public void testAccessors() {
    Person person = new Person();

    person.setFirstName("Jack")
        .setLastName("Bauer")
        .setHeight(100);

    assertEquals("Jack", person.getFirstName());
    assertEquals("Bauer", person.getLastName());
    assertEquals(100, person.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: the question was how to get both normal getter\setter and fluent versions.